# how can I force the screen to stay at maximum brightness in a laptop running on battery?

Tags: laptop, brightness

I have a laptop with Intel integrated drivers running on battery and I would like to force the screen to remain in maximum brightness even when it's idle, for example, when reading a document without using the keyboard or touchpad.

Is there a way to temporarily set the brightness to maximum even when there is no keyboard interaction for minutes/hours?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See Power Management Preferences:

[image]

It might also be handy to put 'put computer to sleep when inactive for' to 'never'

If you want to do this as a command line switch or from a script:

```
gconftool-2 --set --type bool /apps/gnome-power-manager/backlight/idle_dim_battery false
gconftool-2 --set --type bool /apps/gnome-power-manager/backlight/idle_dim_battery true
gconftool-2 --set --type bool /apps/gnome-power-manager/backlight/battery_reduce false
gconftool-2 --set --type bool /apps/gnome-power-manager/backlight/battery_reduce true
```

Answer (score 4):

Use Caffeine, an app that inhibits the screensaver and sleep functions.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:caffeine-developers/ppa

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install caffeine
```